# Interact with Dynamically generated content in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble interacting with dynamically generated content inside of $(document).ready.

I'm working on a webapp where I dynamically generate a lot of the content. I'm using Nodejs and Jquery. In $(document).ready I call a populate function which reads a database, generates many list items, and appends them to the document. This works just fine right now. I encounter problems because I also want each list item to have a more detailed view in a modal box, accessible by either clicking on the list item or a hash in the url. To avoid more calls to the server, each list item has a hidden field which stores the info to put into the modal box. So going to url/#foo will load the page, find the item with id #foo, set up the modal box, and immediately show the modal box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Populate the list on initial page load
    populateList(); //Reads from database, uses template to create list    item elements, and appends to document with .appendchild.

    // Grab the modal box
    var modal = document.getElementById('ModalView');

    // if there is a hash, scroll to that location, and modify and show    the modal box for that item.
    if(location.hash){
        //    Find the matching list item, get the info
        var infoString =  document.getElementById(location.hash).info; 
        // Code to modify modal box based on infoString goes here
        modal.style.display = "block"; // Show Modal box
    }
```

This doesn't work because .getElementByID(location.hash) always returns null. This is not because the id's don't match up, I thoroughly checked that. If I understand correctly, the issue is that my list items aren't fully part of the document until after $(document).ready, meaning that I can't use getElementById. Is there a way for me to get the info for the modal box from my list items in $(document).ready? Or just as the page loads?

Edit: Solved. I made a function for creating the modal box, and put that inside the AJAX function.

Comment: Can you show code of populateList

Answer (score 0):

Inside `$(document).ready` you will have access to all dom elements that are loaded on the initial page load, everything looks ok there.

The problem seems to be that `populateList` is asynchronous and the elements then would not be ready until that function completes and appends them.

An easy way to do this is to pass a callback to the `populateList` function and then call it when in the http request success:

```
function populateList(callback) {
  // ..
  $.get('some-url').success(function() {
    // once you get a successful http response, call the callback:
    callback();
  });
}
```

Then you can get the ids after they are added:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  populateList(function() {
    if (location.hash) {
      var infoString =  document.getElementById(location.hash).info; 
      modal.style.display = "block"; // Show Modal box
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You start to populate your list once the document is ready this means that at the time when you `populateList` the data is still not there so there is no element with your location hash yet. You could use [jQuery.when](http://%20https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait until the data is there and start manipulating it then.

```
function modifiyLocationHash() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalView');
  var infoString =  document.getElementById(location.hash).info; 
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.when(populateList()).then(modifyLocationHash());
}
```